# script to check last file modified

Tags: shell

SHELL SCRIPT TO GET MAIL IF FILE GET MODIFIED

I am writing script to get mail if file has been modified

```
recip="mungsesagar@gmail.com"

file="/root/sagar/ldapadd.sh"

#stat $file

last_modified=$(stat --printf=%y $file | cut -d. -f1)

#echo $last_modified

mail -s "File ldapadd.sh has changed" $recip
```

Now I get mail when I run this script but I want to compare two variables so that I can get mail only if file modified or content changed.
How can I store output in variable to compare

Thanks in advance

Sagar

Answer (score 0):

I would use find to see the last modifyed file

```
#!/bin/bash 
file=timestamp.txt
if [ ! -f timestamp.txt ];
   then
      stat -f %Sm -t %Y%m%d%H%M%S $file > timestamp.txt
   else 
      timestamp=$(stat -f %Sm -t %Y%m%d%H%M%S $file) 
      filetime=$(cat filetime.txt)
      if [ "$filetime" = "$timestamp" ];
         then
            #Do nothing
         else
            echo "$file has been modified" >> /tmp/email.txt
            mail -s "File has changed" "email@domain.com" < /tmp/email.txt
      fi
fi
```

Comment: this works but when i run this script in crontab it generally sends a mail every after 2 mins. I want mail only if file modified

Comment: @user2074481 Check out modified answer.

Comment: That awful indentation causes eye cancer.

Comment: Have slightly modified the format to help ensure Jens does not develop eye cancer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
recip="you@example.com"
file="/root/sagar/ldapadd.sh"
ref="/var/tmp/mytimestamp.dummy"

if [ "$file" -nt "$ref" ]; then
    mail -s "File ldapadd.sh has changed" $recip
fi

touch -r "$file" "$ref" # update our dummy file to match
```

The idea is to store the last seen timestamp of the file of interest by copying it to another file (using `touch`).  Then we always know what the last time was, and can compare it against the current timestamp on the file and email as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, the logic can be changed by storing the output of "ls -ltr filename" in a temp1 file and comparing the same with the ls -ltr output